# C++ string / container allocation

Tags: c++, string, stl

This is probably obvious to a C++ non-noob, but it's stumping me a bit - does a string member of a class allocate a variable amount of space in that class? Or does it just allocate a pointer internally to some other space in memory? E.g. in this example:

```
class Parent {
    public:
    vector<Child> Children;
}

class Child {
    public:
    string Name;
}
```

How is that allocated on the heap if I create a "new Parent()" and add some children with varying length strings? Is Parent 4 bytes, Child 4 bytes (or whatever the pointer size, plus fixed size internal data), and then a random pile of strings somewhere else on the heap? Or is it all bundled together in memory?

I guess in general, are container types always fixed size themselves, and just contain pointers to their variable-sized data, and is that data always on the heap?

Comment: Your last point would be the best way of thinking about it without getting into the optional allocators they take.

Comment: @chris Cool, thanks - yeah, haven't had to use custom allocators for anything yet.

Comment: If you're using VS2010 or VS2012, you could find out yourself by adding the following compiler switch to your project's additional command line options /d1reportSingleClassLayoutxxx (where xxx  is a string used as a substring match against classes to report). Thanks go to Alex Darby of AltDevBlogADay, he pointed this undocumented switch out.  There's also another undocumented compiler option called /d1reportAllClassLayout, but that one lists all the classes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Classes in C++ are always fixed size. When there is a variable sized component, e.g., the elements of a vector or the characters in a string, they may be allocated on the heap (for small strings they may also be embedded in the string itself; this is known as the *small string optimization*). That is, your `Parent` object would contain a `std::vector<Child>` where the `Child` objects are allocated on the heap (the `std::vector<...>` object itself probably keeps three words to its data but there are several ways things may be laid out). The `std::string` objects in `Child` allocate their own memory. That is, there may be quite a few memory allocations.

The C++ 2011 standard thoroughly defines allocators to support passing an allocation mechanism to an object and all its children. Of course, the classes need to also support this mechanism. If your `Parent` and `Child` classes had suitable constructors taking an allocator and would pass this allocator to all members doing allocations, it would be propagated through the system. This way, allocation of objects belong together can be arranged to be in reasonably close proximity.

Comment: Thanks - (to @Grizzly as well), the fact that C++ classes are always fixed size clears up a lot of confusion I've had about memory usage.

Answer (score 3):

Classes in C++ always have a fixed size. Therefore `vector` and `string` can only contain pointers to heap allocated memory* (although they contain typically more data then one pointer, since it also needs to store the length). Therefore the object itself always has a fixed length.

*For `string` this is not entirely correct. Often an optimization technique called short string optimization is used. In that case small strings are embedded inside the object (in the place where otherwise the pointer to heap data would be stored) and heap memory is only allocated if the string is too long.

Answer (score 1):

Yes -- using your words -- container types always fixed size themselves, and just contain pointers to their variable-sized data.

If we have `vector<int> vi;`, the size of `vi` is always fixed, `sizeof(vector<int>)` to be exact, irrespective of the number of `int`'s in `vi`.

Answer (score 0):

> does a string member of a class allocate a variable amount of space in that class?

No, it does not.

> Or does it just allocate a pointer internally to some other space in memory?

No, it does not.

An `std::string` allocates wahtever `sizeof(std::string)` is.

Do not confuse

1. the size of an object
2. the size of the resources, that an object is responsible for.

Comment: The actual character data has to go somewhere though right? So sounds like sizeof(std::string) is the fixed size bit, and then the variable-size string data is somewhere else in memory.

Comment: Yeah, sure. But it's most certainly not inside the class.